# shellscript find and repace xml cdata value

Tags: shell

I have an xml file which has a tag

```
 <string >findme</string>
```

I want to change this tag value with our new value which should become around like that

```
<string ><![CDATA[new value & Task]]></string>
```

But When I try the below command in .sh file then got the wrong value I didn't know why it is seen like that

```
 <string name='app_name'><![CDATA[new value <string name='app_name'>findme</string> Task]]></string>
```

So can Anyone suggest to me where I'm wrong I use below command

```
dynamicValue=<![CDATA[new value & Task]]>

xr="<string name='app_name'>"$dynamicValue"<\/string>" # new replace tag
xs="<string name='app_name'>\(.*\)<\/string>" # searching tag

sed -i "" "s#$xs#${xr}#g" filepath/abx.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like that?

```
replacement='<![CDATA[new value \& Task]]>'
sed -i "s|\(<string name='app_name'>\)[^<]*\(</string>\)|\1${replacement}\2|" filepath/abx.xml
```

**explanation**

```
s                              # use substitution
|                              # separator
\(<string name='app_name'>\)   # save startpattern in arg1 (\1)
[^<]*                          # ignore all characters until the next <
\(</string>\)                  # save endpattern in arg2 (\2)
|                              # separator
\1${replacement}\2             # output: arg1{replacement}arg2
|                              # separator
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @UtLox

There are variable issues

```
dynamicValue='<![CDATA[new value & Task]]>'
```

there was backslash missing belor symbole (&) it should be

```
dynamicValue='<![CDATA[new value \& Task]]>'
```

and then

```
xr="<string name='app_name'>"$dynamicValue"<\/string>" # new replace tag
xs="<string name='app_name'>\(.*\)<\/string>" # searching tag

sed -i "" "s#$xs#${xr}#g" filepath/abx.xml
```